# Electron doesn't install all packages inside package.json

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

Electron packager has packaged my app.But it doesn't have all the node modules as present in my app before packaging. I am forced to manually run npm install inside my packaged folder.

So, the app is not able to perform as expected.

I tried inside package.json

```
"build": {
    "files": [
      "/node_modules/**",
      "package.json"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using your package.json wrong way.
Only "dependencies" will be included to the build if you put some package to "devDependencies" it will be excluded from the build.

Answer (score -1):

use no-prune in build using electron packager  and place all the modules inside devDependencies and then build the app.